# why isn't my label getting updated by combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm using DataBindings from my customer object to by combo box. The behavior I'm trying to achieve is that the label text will reflect what name is selected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Customer selectedCustomer;
    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectedCustomer = new Customer() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jane" };
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = selectedCustomer.FirstName;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        list.Add(new Customer() { Id = 1, FirstName = "John" });
        list.Add(new Customer() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jane" });

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox1.DataSource = list;
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", selectedCustomer, "FirstName");
    }
  }

  public class Customer
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign selected item to `selectedCustomer` field:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedCustomer = (Customer)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    label1.Text = selectedCustomer.FirstName;
}
```

If you want label text to be changed automatically, you should add databinding for label (currently you are adding it to combobox):

```
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", selectedCustomer, "FirstName");
```

But text also will not be updated. Why? Because label is bound to specific instance of customer (one in time of binding adding) - label will reflect changes of customer it is bound to:

```
selectedCustomer.FirstName = "Serge";
```

But again - nothing will happen if you'll change name of customer. Why? Because customer should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise event to notify label about name changed:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _firstName;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get { return _firstName; } 
        set 
        { 
            _firstName = value; // well, it's better to check if value changed
            if (PropertyChanged !=null) 
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
        }
    }        
}
```

Now if you will change name of selected customer, new value will appear in label. That's how databinding works in winforms.

Comment: But isn't DataBindings supposed to update the source automatically (selectedCustomer object in this case)?

Comment: @Rod problem is that you are not updating `selectedCustomer` field when selection changes

Comment: You can add binding for lable `label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", selectedCustomer, "FirstName");`